# Comparing Two XMLs

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, comparison, xmlunit

I have a case in my Java EE application like I need to compare two large auto-generated XMLs. I just need to check if both the XMLs are equal (tags and values).

I tried using `XMLUnit`, but the thing is like it returns `false` even if there are spaces between tags(these XMLs are auto generated right!). Is there any effective way to do this or to write down our own logic ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest StAX. It is the best to work with large files. This could be someting like this

```
private boolean compare(XMLEventReader xr1, XMLEventReader xr2) throws XMLStreamException {
    for (;;) {
        XMLEvent e1 = nextTag(xr1);
        XMLEvent e2 = nextTag(xr2);
        if (e1 == null || e2 == null) {
            return e1 == e2;
        }
        if (!equals(e1, e2)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

private static XMLEvent nextTag(XMLEventReader xr) throws XMLStreamException {
    while (xr.hasNext()) {
        XMLEvent e = xr.nextEvent();
        if (e.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private boolean equals(XMLEvent e1, XMLEvent e2) {
    // compare attributes and content
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

convert the xml to POJO by parsing, using jaxb

Implement the object.equals() in above POJO

then compare the parsed objects using Comparator

Answer (score 0):

You could use an editor with a built-in diff tool. I use the netbeans editor to diff compare files. I find it quick and easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(Boolean.TRUE);

XMLUnit.setNormalizeWhitespace(Boolean.TRUE);

That should work for now.